# php array undefined index, but everything is declared

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, undefined

I've got this problem going on:

```html
Intercepted error

Undefined index: en

Code:  8
Line:  417
```

Code piece one

```html
$page_change_langs = array(
  'de' => '',
  'en' => '',
 );
```

Code piece two

```html
$tpl->assign('page_change_lang_de', $page_change_langs['de']);
 $tpl->assign('page_change_lang_en', $page_change_langs['en']);
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error. The index seems to be there.

complete code: http://pastebin.com/7xZyQgrq

Comment: try setting your array values to null rather than empty strings and see what happens. Also, you have a trailing comma after en's value.

Comment: @VikingBlooded, I don't think trailing comma will cause error. It will produce syntax error not logic error.

Comment: Which line is line no. 417? @Woeler

Comment: line 417 is the last line of the last snippet. Trailing comma didn't do the trick, setting to null also not. :(

Comment: Ok @Woeler, first var_dump $page_change_langs, before $tpl->assign,and tell me what's the result.

Comment: The trailing comma is fine, some styling guidelines even demand it when the array is defined in that way.

Comment: What happens between initialisation of array and trying to access it?

Comment: var_dump $page_change_langs right before $tpl->assign line. Are you sure it's not changed in the middle of way?

Comment: Alright I'm still not getting anything from my code. I'll just post the whole thing here in the OP.

Comment: I'm still not sure what's happening really with Woeler, i'm just getting to nerves. @Mojtaba

Comment: @Woeler, The code you submitted is not completed. You missed the main parts. please paste line# 1 to 418

Comment: Agreed with @Mojtaba

Comment: @Mojtaba here is the complete file http://pastebin.com/1dqSZzsu

Comment: @Woeler, please remove line 538. add var_dump($page_change_langs) right before line 417. Then, see what's output

Comment: @Woeler, I got the solution, Please set " $page_change_langs['en'] = "some definite value"; "

Comment: It's a blank output, also @ShudhanshShekhar I put some random strings in there, still same error.

Comment: Alright, so if I output right after I create the array, all seems fine. When I output before the assign, it gives me a blank...

Comment: are you sure that server_access() === true when you're doing your testing? It doesnt make sense that the array you instantiate would disappear.

Comment: So, I move the array instantiation to the lines right about the assign() and not it seems to work. God knows why.